# How to declare a struct, when struct name is stored in a char array?

Tags: c, struct

I'm a beginner in C programming, and here is a struct definition

```
struct items
{
    char *colour;
    char *type;
};
```

I want to declare the struct, with struct name being the value of its `colour` and `type`. `colour` and `type` are both known variables.

So for eg, if `colour = red` and `type = hat`, the program would declare `struct items red_hat = {red, hat};`

I have tried the following:

```
char item_name[32];
snprintf(item_name, sizeof(item_name), "%s_%s", colour, type);
struct items item_name = {colour, type};
```

But this approach generates a compiler error: *conflicting types for ‘item_name’*. I realised the compiler is using `item_name` as the struct name instead of the string stored in `item_name`.

What should I fix?

Comment: `item_name` can't be the name of your struct because it's the name of your char array. Rename one of them e.g. `struct items roflmao = {colour, type};` (assuming `colour` and `type` are defined somewhere)

Comment: @byxor I'm intending to use the string stored in the char array to be the name of the struct

Comment: variable names must be static at compile time

Comment: The *name* of a struct is only a way to exchange information between the programmer and the compiler. There is no way to access it at run time. It is possible in some dynamic languages, but it is almost always a wrong idea. Long story made short, you should not even try to do that...

Comment: You can always store a string inside the struct as one of the fields if you want to give each instance of the struct some kind of name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve is called *[Metaprogramming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming)*, which involves code that modifies itself. The C programming language focuses on modifying and processing data rather than source code, values of variables that is. Having the names of variables be automatically generated wouldn't be of any benefit to you as they cannot be used as part of the compiled program (they are only labels for YOU, the programmer to keep track of data) and it is a fundamentally wrong approach to try to do so. In the code you provided the char array `item_name` gets assigned with the value `"red_hat"` after the call to `snprintf()`, but it is not substituted as the variable name of the struct you declared next. The *name* of your struct is therefore just `item_name`, same as the char array you declared earlier. C does not allow variables to be reassigned, hence the compiler generating a `conflicting types` error.
You seem to confuse [source code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code) with the binary program that is generated by the [compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler). The latter operates only on values (data such as chars, ints and pointers expressed in [binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary)) that you assigned to the [named variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_(computer_science)).

Feel free to ask away, seemingly stupid questions even as my goal is to clarify these concepts to you. You would also benefit greatly from revising core programming concepts, among them the ones I mentioned.